# Tails: How to connect Tails to a Samba network share?

Tags: debian, networking, samba, smb, shared-folders

**Quick question:**

Is there any way to connect `Tails` to a `Samba`-based `shared-folder` in the local network? Big thanks to [@cacahuatl](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/16504/20730) I found an answer for this part!

**Now the more difficult part is:**

Do I have to configure the `Samba`-server for an access coming from `Tails` in a special way?

I tried to connect to the exchange-folder in three different ways:

1. `smb://HOSTNAME` without success.

   - Causing error: "*Unable to access location. Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused*"
2. `smb://WORKGROUP/HOSTNAME` without success.

   - Causing error: "*Unable to access location. Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused*"
3. `smb://WORKGROUP/HOSTNAME/Exchange` without success.

   - Causing error: "*Unable to access location. Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument*"

---

**My current `/etc/samba/smb.conf` configuration looks like that:**

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
```

and

```
[Exchange]
path = /home/user/Tails-Exchange
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
```

Even if I set the `shared-folder` to `public = yes` and allow `guest ok = yes`, I always get those errors.

---

Thank you very much for your ideas!

[Tails](https://tails.boum.org) = the amnesic incognito live system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All configurations were correct, the problem was different.

One more thanks to [cacahuatl](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/16504/20730) for his note: In Linux-based clients it seems to be necessary to access the `Samba`-server via `IP-address` by default, but **not** by its individual `hostname`.

Therefore you have to determine the `IP-address` of your `Samba`-server related to its `hostname` with the following command:

```
nmblookup <hostname>
```

Afterwards, just copy the displayed `IP-address` into `Tails` file browser and you will have connection success!